# Get path of properties file inside resource directory and not from libraries root directory (both file names are same)

Tags: java

I am trying to get the directory path of the properties file which is located inside the resource directory using the below code.

```
public String getFilePath(String fileName){
    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
    return  file.getParent()+"/";
}
```

My setup will have 3 modules. Module1 has 2 & 3 as a dependency in maven. each  module has its properties file inside the root resource directory - src/main/resources/app.properties

Now if I try to load the path of config.properties from module 2 singleton class using above method, I get the path of module3 properties file. How to get the path of the 2nd module's properties file.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
The answer given in the duplicate question is, to take all resource files and check for the specific string in the path exist or not. I would like to directly get the resource file from the root directory which must be closer to the given class reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read resources from specific JAR file (duplicate paths to file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892639/read-resources-from-specific-jar-file-duplicate-paths-to-file)

Comment: After raising the question, I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730580/how-to-read-several-resource-files-with-the-same-name-from-different-jars, which also takes a list of resources and iterates them. I added the contains part. But I am still curious to know if there any other way to reach the resource root directory located closer to the current class.